# HSQLDB - Move tables across schemas

Tags: hsqldb, rdbms

Is there a way to move a table from a certain schema to another one?
Just for organizational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SQL statement for this in versions up to 2.4.1. However, it is possible to edit the .script file of the database and change the schema in the SQL statements.

Comment: What is the syntax with the recent versions of HSQLDB? `ALTER TABLE schema1.foo RENAME TO schema2.foo`?

Comment: There is no ALTER statement for this. You just shutdown the database and edit the CREATE TABLE statement in the .script file to change the schema name.